# Where is the output from an android instrumented test?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-instrumentation

I managed to get gradle cC to work. My test just prints out and logs one line of text.

```
grep -r text * fails.
```

where is the `system.out` and `logging` output?

thanks

edit: i found the output for the *unit* tests (it's in .../app/build/test-results/). but still no luck with the other.

is there a way to save the output from the instrumented tests somehow?

Comment: Was a copy-paste error, this one works: http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running `gradlew connectedCheck` will generate test results in the build directory, see

```
\build\reports\androidTests\connected\
  and
\build\outputs\androidTest-results\connected\
```

These instrumentation tests will also log their output in LogCat, along with any `Log.d` statements. Using `System.out.print` in your test cases will result in an output like this:

> 01-27 18:05:30.445  32664-32677/your.packagename I/System.out﹕ Test output

If you need to also persist the output you could probably write a gradle task running `adb logcat` and pulling the logs from the device.

Comment: got any ideas about how to write that gradle task?

Comment: @RayTayek What gradle task? `connectedCheck` is part of the android plugin and included in every project, it is the same as `cC` you mentioned in your question

Comment: this one: " ... you could probably write a gradle task running adb logcat .."

Comment: @RayTayek like [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/82ba314ec674f669f91561aab6b69741cb7dab26/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/tasks/InstallTask.groovy) just invoke `adb logcat` and write the output to some file. I don't have any sample code on that :/